# How can I run Lua in MacOS X Terminal like Python3?

Tags: macos, terminal, lua

I know in MacOS X Terminal, if you use the command "python3", it executes any code written **in**   the Terminal. I want to type some code **in** the Terminal. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Get a binary from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

go to https://www.lua.org

click [get started](https://www.lua.org/start.html), read

> If you use Linux or Mac OS X, Lua is either already installed on your
> system or there is a Lua package for it. Make sure you get the latest
> release of Lua (currently 5.4.2).

Alternatively build it from source

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/readme.html

Answer (score -1):

Lua 5.3.5 comes on the newer macs or is installed with system updates. Just go to a terminal window and type lua.

Comment: Yes, but it says that "Lua" is not a command. Is there a way for me to get a file or something?

Comment: Which newer macs?

Comment: Did you type it in all lowercase -  lua

Comment: @lhf  well its onmy 2020 iMac and I'm pretty sure I read it was on 2018 Macs as well.  I think, but I'm not sure, it was on my 2010 iMac.